# Check value in datatable with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq, datatable

I am creating a Word Cloud and so I am splitting my sentences in Linq using Regex and grouping the words and taking the count of them. However, I don't want some blacklist words to appear in my cloud, so I get those words in a datatable (dtBlackList) and check with Linq as shown in the code below

```
var result = (Regex.Split(StringsForWordCloud, @"\W+")
                   .GroupBy(s => s, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                   .Where(q => q.Key.Trim() != "")
                   .Where(q => (dtBlackList.Select("blacklistword = '" + q.Key.Trim() + "'").Count() == 0))
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                   .Select(p => new { Word = p.Key, Count = p.Count() })
              ).Take(200);
```

Will this query affect my performance badly? Is this the right way to check against a datatable?

Comment: This ain't the right area where you can ask **Is this code good or bad**. Better add your post here [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is `StringsForWordCloud`? Can you check SQL profiler to see what sort of queries are generated when your code runs?

Comment: StringsForWordCloud contains the sentences of which I want to create word cloud of. My backend is not sql server.

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ query as this one will execute a query for each word found with the `Regex.Split` operation. I'm referring to this line of code:

```
.Where(q => (dtBlackList.Select("blacklistword = '" + q.Key.Trim() + "'").Count() == 0))
```

I've had to deal with a lot of performance problems on the project I'm working right now, caused by situations similar to this one.

In general, performing a query to check or complete the data extracted in your database is not a good practice.

In your case, I think it's much better to write a single query that will extract the blacklist words and then exclude that list from the dataset you have just extracted. As follows:

```
var words = Regex.Split(StringsForWordCloud, @"\W+")
    .GroupBy(s => s, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Where(q => q.Key.Trim() != "")
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(p => new { Word = p.Key, Count = p.Count() });

// Now extract all the word in the blacklist
IEnumerable<string> blackList = dtBlackList...

// Now exclude them from the set of words all in once
var result = words.Where(w => !blackList.Contains(w.Word)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Take(200);
```